# Compare & Contrast to get deeper understanding of similarities and differences between Punchy vs Pithy

Tags: meaning-in-context, semantics, comparatives

> Reference :  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pithy
>
> Pithy adjective 1 : consisting of or abounding in pith 2 : having
> substance and point : tersely cogent

> Reference : https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/punchy
>
> punchy adjective ˈpən-chē  punchier; punchiest Synonyms of punchy 1 a
> : having punch : FORCEFUL, SPIRITED The collection is strong on
> punchy, memorable music and weak on lyrics. —People Weekly He leans
> abruptly forward and speaks with the punchy emphasis of an inveterate
> politician. —Bill Bryson b : VIVID, VIBRANT These punchy colors glide
> on and blend easily into mere hints of color. —Elle c : ZESTY It is an
> elegant dish, although the sauce seems overly polite now. I remember
> it when the fresh coriander was an intense and punchy flavor.
> —Caroline Bates 2 : DAZED, PUNCH-DRUNK … I arrived in Paris after a
> thirteen-hour flight, unwashed, unshaved, punchy from jet lag,
> discombobulated … —David Berlinski

Could some please give an elaborate explanation on the similarities and differences between Punchy as Pithy?  Please give contextual examples as well.  Thanks in advance

Comment: What specifically do the dictionary entries fail to explain?

Comment: What's the difference between punches and pith? (And doesn't the dictionary give contextual examples? What kind of contextual example do they fail to provide?)

Comment: The words are barely related to each other. What is there to compare?

Answer (score -1):

Here's a pithy definition of "pithy":

> A pithy remark gives you something to chew on.

And here's a punchy definition of "punchy":

> A punchy remark doesn't dance around; it smacks you in the head.